# Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

No sé dónde está el error.

Se quiere saber el Cantidad Total de la tabla detallepedidos, donde los NombreContacto termine por a y su códigocliente sea 10.

```
SELECT SUM(Cantidad) FROM detallepedidos 
WHERE (SELECT NombreContacto, CodigoPedido FROM Clientes 
WHERE (NombreContacto LIKE '%a') AND (CodigoCliente=10));
```

> ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cantidad no esta definida en la subquery- aparte en la subquery sobran unos parentesis

Comment: Cuales sobran los parentesis

Comment: Falta información en tu pregunta. Intenta añadir el diseño de las tablas de las que estas intentando obtner datos para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: `WHERE (NombreContacto LIKE '%a') AND (CodigoCliente=10)` No tiene sentido poner parentesis en un solo AND. Pero vamos que el problema es el otro. Cantidad no existe.

Comment: @JDev Estos parentesis los suelen poner los mismos programas de gestion de BD, de todas maneras no afectan en nada a la consulta.

Comment: @Marc ya se que no afectan a la query pero si a la legibilidad, por eso le he dicho 'aparte' no que fuera su error.

Comment: puesta la imagen

Comment: Ahora que lo veo mejor, esa query no tiene sentido. Haces básicamente un un  `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE a, b`  En un where tienen que ir operaciones de true/false separadas por AND, OR ...  Eso no va a funcionar en la vida.

Comment: como podria hacer con eso una subconsulta

Comment: ¿que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente?

Comment: Se quiere saber el Cantidad Total de la tabla detallepedidos, donde los NombreContacto termine por a y su códigocliente sea 10.

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser por subconsulta?

Comment: Aparte pon toda esa información en la pregunta

Comment: si tiene que ser por subconsulta

Comment: Ya lo tienes como respuesta.

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No deberías de usar esa subquery en el `WHERE`, ya que espera como resultado una columna y no dos (NombreContacto y CodigoPedido).

Hasta donde puedo ver por la definición de tu base de datos, deberías usar algún `JOIN`.

Por ejemplo, tu consulta podría quedar así.

```
SELECT
    SUM(det.Cantidad)
FROM detallepedidos det
JOIN pedidos pe
    ON det.CodigoPedido = pe.CodigoPedido
JOIN clientes cli
    ON cli.CodigoCliente = pe.CodigoCliente
WHERE
    cli.NombreContacto LIKE '%a'
    AND cli.CodigoCliente = 10
```

Comment: Me resulto bien

Comment: ¿y donde esta la subconsulta?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Si te refieres a la subconsulta de la que hable en mi respuesta, a la que hago referencia, esa está en su pregunta, en el `WHERE`, es la que le digo que es el problema por la cantidad de columnas que da. Si te refieres a alguna que aparentó que quería modificar, no está, precisamente por eso sugerí el uso del `JOIN` como alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

Atendiendo a los comentarios realizados por el creador de la pregunta

Básicamente lo que se hace en la subconsulta es obtener todos los CodigoPedidos que cumplen los requisitos de que el NombreContacto del cliente acaba por a y el CodigoCliente es 10.

Posteriormente se hace la suma de la Cantidad de los detallespedidos que son de ese pedido.

```
SELECT SUM(Cantidad) FROM detallepedidos dp
WHERE dp.CodigoPedido IN (SELECT CodigoPedido FROM pedidos p
             JOIN clientes c ON c.CodigoCliente = p.CodigoCliente
             WHERE c.NombreContacto LIKE '%a' AND c.CodigoCliente = 10)
```

Comment: me dice que no existe la columna db

Comment: No hay ninguna columna db. Copiala de nuevo y prueba.